# How to change alfresco start directory?

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, alfresco

I rsync-ed from old working alfresco server entire /dir/alfresco-5.0/* to /dir/52/

52 is the name I had for alfresco dir on the new server.

Obviously this didn't work when I restarted alfresco on the new server because inside /dir/52 there are files configured to work with /dir/alfresco-5.0.

I can change the name of the directory but I'm guessing this won't work since alfresco program is configured to look at /dir/52.

I want to know how to configure alfresco to use the new name I when I change /dir/52 to /dir/alfresco-5.0.

Comment: Did you check your `alfresco-global.properties` file for the directory references?

Comment: I changed it by editing /etc/init.d/alfresco but that wasn't enough. systemctl status alfresco is showing that java is still using the old dir "├─21243 /opt/52/java/bin/java "

Comment: Ok, i killed the java pid and restarted alfresco, everything seems fine but the site doesn't load.

Answer (score 0):

Places in a 5.2 Alfresco installation where the Alfresco home directory might be specified:

- alfresco-global.properties
- catalina.sh
- ctl.sh
- setenv.sh
- solr.in.sh

You might try a recursive grep for the old directory name starting in /dir/alfresco-5.0 to find them all.